# how to get a value from a datatable in webservice to a HTML ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-services, html

I have a datatable in my web service it goes like this

```
 [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod]
        public DataTable mydbCon()
            {
SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=myds;Initial Catalog=name;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=pwd");
                SqlCon.Open();
                SqlCommand SqlComm = new SqlCommand();
                SqlComm.Connection = SqlCon;
                SqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                SqlComm.CommandText = "select password from tbl_login where username='aby';";
                DataTable EmployeeDt = new DataTable("tbl_login");
                SqlDataAdapter SqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlComm);
                SqlDa.Fill(EmployeeDt);
                return EmployeeDt;
            }
```

and I am having a Ajax call in my HTML page it goes like this and I am not getting a value it shows the error message

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function GetAge() {
           jQuery.support.cors = true;
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               dataType: "json",
               jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
               async: false,
               url: "http://localhost:50113/Service1.asmx/mydbCon",
               data: "{}",
               success: function (msg) {
                    $('#divToBeWorkedOn').html(msg.d);
                },
               error: function (e) {
                   $('#divToBeWorkedOn').html("unavailable");
               }
           });
       }
      </script>
```

Comment: I think your url should be /Service.asmx/mydbCon.Try that and see.

Comment: service1.asmx is the page I created the webservice

Comment: Ya I know did you try that url that I mentioned?

Comment: did you mark your service with `[ScriptService]` attribute?

Comment: [ScriptService] attribute is already defined in my code

Comment: try to remove `data` option. And remove `jsonp` as well.

Comment: I would try adding `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]` and use `/Service1.asmx/mydbCon` as the URL. Also, I'm unsure if you can actually parse a DataTable to JSON.

Comment: I removed data and jsonp but still it didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at last I found out the answer you need to add '.text' after 'msg' the line $('#divToBeWorkedOn').html(msg.text);

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function GetAge() {
         jQuery.support.cors = true;
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             async: false,
             url: 'http://localhost:50113/Service1.asmx/mydbCon?wsdl',
             success: function (msg) {
                   $('#divToBeWorkedOn').html(msg.text); 

             },
             error: function (e) {
                 $('#divToBeWorkedOn').html("unavailable");
             }
         });
     } 
  </script>
```

Thanks palmpalm,Yuriy and everyone else for your support

Answer (score 1):

Extract from the [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) :
"json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. In jQuery 1.4 the JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. (See json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.)

So if your webservice doesn't response in proper JSON format, the error case will be executed.

So two solution here :

1. As suggested by [sQve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1606912/sqve), just try adding [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] to response in JSON format.
2. Change your javascript code to accept direct data and return only the "msg.d" data from your webservice :

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       function GetAge() {
           jQuery.support.cors = true;
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               async: false,
               url: "http://localhost:50113/Service1.asmx/mydbCon",
               success: function (msg) {
                   $('#divToBeWorkedOn').html(msg);
               },
               error: function (e) {
                   $('#divToBeWorkedOn').html("unavailable");
               }
         });
     }
     </script>
   ```

Why post a full JSON object (serialize and unserialize) with many data if you're only using one property ?
Make it simple :)

Comment: I am getting a error like this                             Microsoft JScript runtime error: DOM Exception: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR (3)

Comment: Seems to be a problem when you access to the $('#divToBeWorkedOn') object right ?
Did you use debug tools like firebug or something like ?
May be usefull in your javascript developpement.